# Login to tty as guest?

Tags: login, tty, guest-session

I was wondering if it is possible to log into a tty session (not the GUI) as a guest?

As far as my observation goes the guest session provided at login are served by `lightdm` which dynamically creates those guest accounts (correct me if I'm wrong) but how would that be done in a tty login because it requires a *login* and a *password* ?

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't and I will try to explain you why. There are two things that prevents you to login to tty as guest:

1. The default shell for guest accounts is set to `/bin/false`. You can check this with the following command (the shell is set on the last field on each line):

   ```
   grep guest /etc/passwd
   ```

   `/bin/false` is just a binary that immediately exits, returning false, when its called, **so when someone who has false as shell logs in, they're immediately logged out when false exits**.
2. **The password for any guest account is disabled by default** and this is absolutely normally: if you invite someone in your house, you don't give him your house keys.

   Because of this nobody can't login *normally*<sup>[1]</sup> in any interactive *login*<sup>[2]</sup> shell. You can check this with the following command (the password is set on the second field on each line):

   ```
   grep guest /etc/shadow
   ```

[1] I said normally, because you can switch from a *real* user to a user with the password disabled using `sudo su user_with_no_passwd` (like in real life: when someone knocks on your door, you open him with your keys).

[2] tty1-6 wast (and I suppose it will be) all the time an **interactive login shell**. And this world - *login* - it suggest me that I must to have a password to get over it (like in real life: when you see a lock, you need a key to open it).

---

Now, if you still want to login to tty as guest, follow the instructions from the below *ttyrecord* image:

[image: ttyrecord]

And now you can go in tty and login as guest... *a guest with password... which means that it is not anymore a guest...*

Comment: Just a tip, you don't have to pipe `cat` into `grep` when dealing with files. For example your first command above could be written `grep guest /etc/passwd`.

Comment: The only reason I aint commenting on this that my `/etc/passwd` seems to be different then the one in this gif. And I doubt it has a guest-xyz user in it altogether. Will check and follow-up. *PS: sorry for the late response.*

Comment: @BleedingFingers You will see guest accounts in your `/etc/passwd` only if one ore more people are logged as guest in the GUI. See also: [Why there are many guest accounts on my system?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/337861/why-there-are-many-guest-accounts). Anyway, consider that my answer is until the horizontal line.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, I would suggest doing it the "old fashioned" way. Simply create a new user name GuestUser. Give them limited permissions, and you can optionally give them a password or not. If you want GuestUser to have no password, you will probably have to modify PAM authentication a bit to allow passwordless logins. Good luck :)