# How do I remove extra Guest accounts in Ubuntu MATE? / How do I get my guest account to work?

Tags: lightdm, mate, guest-session

I'm having a problem with guest sessions in Ubuntu MATE; every time I tried to log in, it tells me that I can't access the .ICEauthority file (can't remember its location), boots me out, and creates a new account, named Guest. So not only can I not get into my guest account, but whenever I try, it creates a new account called Guest. I can't log in to them (password locked and I have no idea what it is) and they don't show up in Users and Groups. Does anybody know how to solve these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As regards the error message, I can reproduce it on Ubuntu MATE 20.10. This is the complete error message I see:

> Could not update ICEauthority file /run/user/998/ICEauthority

However, if I close the dialog, it takes me to the guest session after a long (almost a minute) delay. That's apparently not normal and probably a MATE bug, and it would be good if you could [report it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate/+filebug).

As regards the Guest users in `/etc/passwd` etc. they are there because you didn't log out from the Guest Session properly. If you want to clean it up from previous failed attempts to enter a Guest Session, please see this Ask Ubuntu question:

[Why there are many guest accounts on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337861/why-there-are-many-guest-accounts-on-my-system)

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, I found Ubuntu MATE to be a hot mess already so I switched to normal old Ubuntu GNOME. However, this is StackExchange, so there's bound to be someone else who needs your help!