# unknown guest account with password created

Tags: login, password, lightdm, guest-session, guest-additions

i am using ubuntu 20.04 i want guest session for students so i enabled it by following

How to enable Guest session on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa Linux
30 April 2020 by Lubos Rendek
terminal commands
1.sudo apt install lightdm

2.switch to lightdm

3.sudo sh -c 'printf "[Seat:*]\nallow-guest=true\n" > /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-enable-guest.conf'

4.reboot

issue:
1.now i am seeing unknown guest account with password in login screen but there is no such a account i created
2.whenever guest session switched account new guest account with password created

need solution to remove that account

Comment: Your step #3 added a line to the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-enable-guest.conf`.  If you want to undo what you did, you can just edit that file and remove that line.  You might also want to uninstall `lightdm` if you really want to undo everything you did.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why there are many guest accounts on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337861/why-there-are-many-guest-accounts-on-my-system)